# TabBar icon don't show and options don't work in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I had problem with TabBar `react-navigation`

`| react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.13 |`

`| react-native 0.48.4|`

`| node v6.11.4 |`

`| npm 3.10.10 |`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from "expo"

import {
    TabNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const MyHomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
    <Text>HOME</Text>
);

const MyNotificationScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
    <Text>NOTIFICATION</Text>
);

MyHomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
            name={'md-checkmark-circle'}
            size={26}
            style={{ color: tintColor }}
        />
    ),
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false
};

MyNotificationScreen.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'People',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
            name={'md-checkmark-circle'}
            size={26}
            style={{ color: tintColor }}
        />
    ),
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false
};

const App = TabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: MyHomeScreen,
        },
        Notifications: {
            screen: MyNotificationScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#e91e63' : '#fff',
        },
    }
);



export default () => <App />
```

[Live preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t5AQ.png)

Problem is icon don't show and label is visible but i set `showLabel` as `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showIcon & showLabel are options for the TabNavigator itself (under tabBarOptions), not the screen navigationOptions.

Comment: Thanks dude! Works :)